# Threads in production cause too many database connections error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to do a do a threaded active record query. It tests properly on development but it gives me a `PG::Error (FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already)` error on production. I have the exact same pool size for both development and production. Here is a snippet of the code I am trying to run in a thread:

```
threads = []
acs.each do |a|
  threads << Thread.new do
    activity = Hash.new
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      whouser = User.find(a.whoid)
      target = User.find(a.targetid) if !(a.targetid.blank?)  
      activity["user_name"] = whouser.user_name
      activity["user_id"] = whouser.id
      activity["f_uid"] = whouser.f_uid
      ....
    end
  end
end
threads.each { |t| t.join }
```

Any insight on this would be amazing!

P.S I am testing production and development on my development computer but running it as a production. It is having the same problems on my actual production server as well.

Comment: It's very unusual to see `Hash.new` without any arguments. `{ }` is almost always a better way of achieving the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only create so many threads before you will exhaust the number of connections to your server. It would be better to set up a simple work queue and have each thread pop peck away at this list until done.

Example:

```
tasks = acs
threads = [ ]

10.times do
  threads << Thread.new do
    while (task = tasks.pop)
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

The `Thread.join` component would remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will probably still implement this but I found out that the problem was a gem I was using "ar-octopus" was not thread-safe. I will mark this as the answer though! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that would be a problem. The thread safety of various libraries varies considerably.

Comment: You probably want to also use ruby builtin -> tasks = Queue.new instead of an array since it has the locks needed to keep your queue threadsafe.